# Why does this apache camel rest configuration allow for other mediatypes than json, even if configured only to consume jsons?

Tags: java, spring, rest, apache-camel

I am creating a route using Apache camel with the following configuration:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import org.apache.camel.Consume;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RestToKafkaRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    private final Config     
    config=ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").resolve();

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    final String host = config.getString("infrastructure.rest.host");
    final Integer port = config.getInt("infrastructure.rest.port");
    final String context = config.getString("infrastructure.rest.context");
    final String path = config.getString("infrastructure.rest.path");
    final String endpoint = config.getString("infrastructure.kafka.endpoint");

    System.out.printf("Consuming from %s. Sending to %s\n", host + ":" + port + "/" + context + "/" + path, endpoint);

    restConfiguration()
            .component("jetty")
            .host(host)
            .port(port);

    rest("/" + context)
            .post("/" + path)
            .consumes("application/json").route().routeId(path)
            .to(endpoint);
    }
}
```

After configuration, I perform a test:

```
@Test
public void callRestServiceWithHandledMethodTest() {

    given()
            .body("this_is_not_a_json")
            .when()
            .post("/{path}", path)
            .then()
            .log().status()
            .statusCode(200);
}
```

This test passes, although in my opinion it should fail, since the body is not json, but plain text.

My questions:

What does the method `.consumes()` actually do?

Why does it allow for datatypes other than application/json?

Shouldn't the test fail?

How can I make the rest service reject datatypes other than json?

Answer (score 0):

The media-type is set as the content-type HTTP header, so call the REST service with something in this header that is not json. Also you need to turn on client request validation to have Camel reject it automatically. If you are not using this, then it depends on the actual http component you have chosen for rest-dsl whether it may reject the request or not (you are using jetty).

See the documentation about client request validation: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/rest-dsl.adoc